# Feasibility of humidity controlled minifan

Tags: dc

I am thinking of constructing a DC operated minifan out of a humistor. I looked up some sources that says humistors typically operate on AC. Is there any way of making this work on DC input?

Comment: What does the datasheet for your proposed humistor say? A digital sensor such as DHT11  + Arduino or other microcontroller might be easier.

Comment: There are multiple types of humistors, there are at least resistive types and capacitive types. If you're using a resistive type, DC would be the sensible sensing method, whereas capacitive ones will need some sort of AC to sense the value. Alternatiely you could use a humidity sensor IC, which will then communicate with your uC via SPI or IC2 or any other interface you can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you **must** use AC to measure humistors. Any significant DC component will damage them. Any time you have the possibility of electrolytic action, DC is generally verboten (eg. liquid crystal displays).

[Here](http://humidjr.com/pdf/JRSHR.pdf) is a datasheet for a typical product from a Chinese manufacturer.

[image]

Maximum excitation is specified as 1.5VAC and frequency 500Hz to 2kHz. and test condition is 1.0VAC sine wave at 1kHz.

From the datasheet we find this warning (emphasis added):

> 8. Note
>
>    (1) Avoid polarizing, actuates the voltage or the electric current which the sensor uses **should not include the direct current
>    ingredient**
>
>    (2) Please make sure test with LCR AC, **not direct currency (sic)
>    multimeter**

One approach would be to make a sine wave with some circuit such as a phase-shift oscillator (since frequency is not too important) or create a more-or-less sinusoidal signal by filtering a square wave, then use that to excite a bridge or half-bridge then a precision rectifier to give a DC  level related to the resistance of the humistor. Temperature compensation is also required for most applications.

Given that level of complexity, you may prefer to  use a polymer capacitive type which can be used to make an oscillator that has a relative humidity-dependent frequency.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment…

There are multiple types of humidity sensors: there are at least resistive types, capacitive types and dedicated ICs (which, while they may contain a resistive or capacitive element, could have any type of interface with your control IC).

If you're using a resistive type of humistor, DC would be the sensible sensing method. You put a known voltage across a defined potential divider or sensing H-bridge, and then measure the voltage across the humistor. All of that is simple DC stuff. If you want, this method could be built using just passive component and a few transistors (and maybe a relay depending on your fan).

Whereas capacitive ones will need some sort of AC to sense the value. Clearly this gets more complicated as you’re trying to detect change of capacitance. While it is possible to do this with pretty much only passives, it would have a very limited operating range and have a very complicated collection of circuitry. However there probably exist micro controllers which are designed to do the hard stuff for you, so you just need to find a sensible one of them and use their application note.

Alternatively you could use a humidity sensor IC. This is this easiest way, as you then have a known entity which should communicate in whatever method you could want. Often they are I2C or SPI, though I’m sure analogue voltage or current outputs are common. Clearly this method requires the use of a microcontroller/processor of some sort, but this would be my method as it gives lots tunability and options for further projects (adding display screens etc).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the response. In our project, we are required to use only passive components, semiconductors, and op amps. Also our input is confined to the use of DC only, thus my only option is to consider using the resistive type humidity sensor (humistor).

Comment: I intend to use the humistor in my circuit as a speed control of the fans. What should I construct then? I'm now nonfused about the H-bridge.

Comment: If you want speed control with descreete components, that's going to be tricky. You'll want to do a sensing H bridge and then amplify that signal as an input into a PWM driver. You might be able to do it another way, but wouldn't be my choice. I'd stick with just ON OFF control using a potential divider as an input into a transistor (darlington pair or as an input into a relay depending on the power requirements of the motor). I suggest you do more research into it, design the ON OFF version first and then see where that takes you. Post a new question if you want specifics.

Comment: I've posted a new one. I'll appreciate your response once again.

Comment: My bad. Here's the link.https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/617369/feasibility-of-humidity-controlled-minifan-part-2