# Feasibility of humidity controlled minifan part 2

Tags: sensor, humidity

Previously, I asked about the type of input that I should employ in my project which is a humidity controlled minifan out of a humistor, and I considered using DC. Now I'm asking how construct the circuit.

I wanted to use the humistor as a voltage control to regulate the speed of the fans just like the capacitor control in AC fans, but unlike the capacitor controlled fans which needs to be manually switched in order to change the speed of the fan, the humistor voltage control can alter the fan speed depending in the humidity.

Unfortunately, I do not know if this works.

Comment: What's your current schematic look like? Have you attempted a simple on-off circuit? What research have you done about potential dividers?

Comment: Not yet. But perhaps I could send it to you later.

Comment: Regarding the potential divider, I did some research regarding the operation of voltage control in AC fans, especially the potentiometer based ones. I'll follow the same circuit but I'll use humistor in lieu of resistor knob.